# Wrong savings in XML file C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have a problem with savings data in XML file. I need to change value of selected node but every time is changing a value of the first node. Any advices?

```
Values v = new Values();
a = v.ValueNameFromList;
System.Xml.XmlDocument xmlDoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.Load(path1);
    foreach (Test element in dpc.estList)
    {
            if (element.name == a)
            {
                xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("Collection/Elements/Element/Calories").InnerText = GetPoints.countPoints.ToString();
                xmlDoc.Save(path1);
            }
        }
```

Here it's xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Collection>
  <Elements>
    <Element>
      <name>Cooking</name>
      <Calories>100</Calories>
    </Element>
    <Element>
      <name>Dancing</name>
      <Calories>0</Calories>
    </Element>
    <Element>
      <name>Walking</name>
      <Calories>0</Calories>
    </Element>
  </Elements>
</Collection>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your XPath is selecting always the first item from the tree.

You need to select correct node. So use `text()` to create a condition on node's value and then navigate up to parent and select `Calories` subside.

```
"Collection/Elements/Element/name[text()="+a+"]/../Calories"
```

Comment: I get an error abou NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: @Quicki maybe value of `a` is sometimes outside the values that are in the XML? you need to have a check for those cases in your code

Answer (score 1):

Use LNQ to Xml

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(path);

foreach (Test element in dpc.estList)
{
    if (element.name == a)
    {
        var selected = 
            doc.Root
               .Descendants("Element")
               .FirstOrDefault(element => element.Element("name").Value.Equals(a));

        selected.Element("Calories").Value = GetPoints.countPoints.ToString();
        doc.Save(path);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have an error Type `System.Xml.XmlDocument' does not contain a definition for `Root' and no extension method `Root' of type `System.Xml.XmlDocument' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: I am using `XDocument` you need add reference to `System.Xml.Linq`

Comment: You cannot if you using `XDocument` and not `XmlDocument`

Comment: Could it be because I use Unity?

Answer (score 0):

The key point here is to master the XPath expressions to look for the right element to be changed; I would suggest avoiding using operators like `..` because that can lead into performance issues.

Also, consider you must sanitize the `elementName` value, as if it contains characters like `'` it will break your code in a *sql injection* similar way.

```
var elementName = "Dancing";
var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(@"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Collection>
  <Elements>
    <Element>
      <name>Cooking</name>
      <Calories>100</Calories>
    </Element>
    <Element>
      <name>Dancing</name>
      <Calories>0</Calories>
    </Element>
    <Element>
      <name>Walking</name>
      <Calories>0</Calories>
    </Element>
  </Elements>
</Collection>");

// be careful: xml is case-sensitive!
// maybe you want to change the "name" element to "Name" to be using the same casing convention
var calories = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode($"/Collection/Elements/Element[name='{elementName}']/Calories");
if (calories != null)
    calories.InnerText = "X";

xmlDoc.Save(Console.Out);
```